# Security risks posed by user generated filenames on a webserver

Tags: web-application, file-upload

Do filenames themselves pose a security risk?

We have a webserver, users can upload files to the server.  The files are temporarily stored on the server, then moved to S3.  The filenames are recorded into our MySQL database and eventually included in the HTML & CSS that our webserver produces.  The filenames themselves are never changed from what the user uploads.

In terms of security, is there any vulnerability that can be exploited with a mere filename?  Should we be changing the filenames of uploaded content, or is it safe to simply store the filenames as they are?

Comment: Please supply more information such as what kind of files are allowed? Are these files checked (e.g. reading the file header)? Another somewhat old vulnerability that comes to mind is null byte injection.

Comment: @Jeroen-ITNerdbox assume any kind of file can be uploaded.  I am interested in security risks posed specifically by not changing the filenames of user-uploaded files - not necessarily interested in all the security risks imposed in user-uploaded files

Comment: A mere filename poses no risk. But if your code makes decisions or actions based on invalid assumptions about the filename (like parsing the name, processing based on file extension ...) or if it is possible to include the file as code into your own code (i.e. insecure include path for PHP) then it might be a risk. Only, nothing is  known about your code and server setup so this question cannot be answered.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is overwriting files which could tamper with the integrity of existing files.

Comment: You can certainly exploit using various unsupported characters. The actual name is not the problem. There's a problem when you start to process it with something.

Comment: If they're going into an SQL database the filename could be an SQL injection attempt

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I am not looking for security risks in my code - I am looking for the security concerns that should be considered regarding filenames of user-uploaded content.

Comment: @Jimmery: Again, the name by itself poses no risk. The risk is in what you are doing with the name, which means your code, your system setup etc. Only, nothing is known about how the name gets used by these.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Could the file name compromise the uploader of the file? e.g. Could a hacker use the file name to know what to look for on the uploader’s system?

Comment: @IanWarburton: *"...the name by itself poses no risk. The risk is in what you are doing with the name, which means your code, your system setup etc."* - exactly this applies to your question too. The name is just some bytes which have no inner meaning. It gets only a  meaning and thus potential risks through the way how the name is used, which is unknown in this case.

Comment: @steffenullrich The use would be knowing what to look for on someone’s system. I.e. John uploads mybankdetails.txt and then a hacker knows to search for this file on John’s computer.

Comment: @IanWarburton: Nothing in the questions implies that the uploaded file could be visible or accessible by others.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, all user controlled input poses a potential security risk and should never be trusted.**

But, if the file name is a threat to your application depends on how you process the file and the file name internally. I would suggest to sanitize the file name when the user executes the file upload.

For test cases, best practices and prevention methods see the [Unrestricted File Upload](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unrestricted_File_Upload) page at OWASP.

Comment: It's not possible to sanitize it as you don't know where it will be used.